# Did Basavanna really conduct inter caste marriage?

Tags: history, shaivism, india, shivadvaita

Some leftists argue that Basavanna was a social reformer and did not see difference in castes. They also argue that Basavanna did not worship temple Gods ,but Veerashaivas argue that these facts are fake and lingayatas do idol worship. Is it true that Basavanna was really a social reformer?

Comment: The question in the title isn't matching with the one in the body. Is your main question the following "Did he conduct inter-caste marriage?" or is it "Was Basavana a social reformer?"